# How can I pop current screen before navigating to next screen in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using `react-native-router-flux` in my project. I have a Login screen. Operator enters his username and password and then click on Login button. `Settings` screen displays once he authenticated successfully. There is a back button in this screen that brings operator back to Login screen again. I am looking for a way to pop Login screen from back stack before navigating to the next screen. By doing so, click on back button of Settings screen, Home screen displays.

Seems my following code doesn't work properly.

```
private onLoginPress = (): void => {
    .....

    // Display Settings screen if isValidatingForSettings is True otherwise display Home screen
    NavigationActions.pop();
    navigate(this.props.isValidatingForSettings ? Types.navSettings : Types.navHome);
}
```

My HomeScreen resets the stack. HomeScreen.componentDidMount() could check and redirect to prefs, but that seems hacky. I am looking for a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

I could figure it out by Back button customization of my Senttings screen.
I created a `renderBackButton`:

```
const renderBackButton = () => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={ () => navigate(Types.navHome) }>
        <Icon
          name='angle-left'
          size={ Metrics.icons.large }
          color={ Colors.grayXS }
          style={{ marginTop: -10 }}
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default renderBackButton();
```

and then assigned it into `Scene` of this screen:

```
<Scene
    hideNavBar={ false }
    key={ Types.Settings }
    component={ SettingsScreen }
    title={ I18n.t('settings') }
    renderBackButton={() => renderBackButton}/>
```